# fmt::format access violation

Tags: c++, access-violation, fmt

I have no idea what's wrong with this. Recently built a new PC and it worked just fine (same project, same settings in visual studio, etc). But for some reason any time I try `fmt::format` it will give me an access violation exception. Though if formatting with spdlog for example it works fine.

```
const char* TextureException::what() const noexcept
{
    mWhat = fmt::format("{}\n[Info] {}", getType(), getInfo()); // access violation
    return mWhat.c_str();
}
```

`getType()` just returns some identifying information, its hard coded right now so its not a nullptr or anything. Same with `getInfo()` (except this returns file and line number)

And even just testing some code will give me an access violation error:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string test = fmt::format("Testing {}", 32); // access violation
    std::cout << test << "\n";
}
```

I am completely stumped as to why this is no longer working on the new PC.

Comment: Tried rebuilding fmt library?

Comment: Effectively, when things are really strange, one must do a full rebuild. Under Visual Studio if one does a lot of editions and compile at the same time or when using edit&continue, or playing with history a lot, that kind of issue do occurs from time to time.Most of the time, if code is correct but behavior is weird, then somehow some files get corrupted.

Comment: @ALX23z I use vcpkg to handle libraries, so when I built my new PC I did a fresh install/build of all the libraries I use

Comment: @Phil1970 Unless you mean something other than `Build > Rebuild Solution` unfortunately that did not work

Answer (score 2):

in my case, there is no problem when the formatting string is unicode, access violation occurred only when it was ascii.

changing setting visual studio>project property>vcpkg>Target and Configuration Specific>Vcpkg Configuration to Debug in Debug Build solved the problem.